# How to write customer order by in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have some sample data like this.

Here are order by logic

1. first order by `createDate`
2. second order by `col1` contain word **Tom** need care uppercase and lowercase
3. third order by `col2` don't care uppercase and lowercase

Sample data:

```
|   col1 |        col2 |           createDate |
+--------+-------------+----------------------+
|  S Amy |   Apple pie | 2018-06-19T00:00:00Z |
|  U Tom |   Apple pie | 2018-06-19T00:00:00Z |
|  kevin |  banana pie | 2018-06-18T00:00:00Z |
|  U tOm |   Apple pie | 2018-06-19T00:00:00Z |
|  k tom | Apple juice | 2018-06-18T00:00:00Z |
| Stanly |   Apple pie | 2018-06-18T00:00:00Z |
|    Tom |  banana pie | 2018-06-19T00:00:00Z |
```

Sample data sqlfiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/6c729/1

I have been tried this query. I don't know to achieve my expected result.

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
ORDER BY createDate DESC
```

Current results:

```
|   col1 |        col2 |           createDate |
+--------+-------------+----------------------+
|  S Amy |   Apple pie | 2018-06-19T00:00:00Z |
|  U Tom |   Apple pie | 2018-06-19T00:00:00Z |
|  U tOm |   Apple pie | 2018-06-19T00:00:00Z |
|    Tom |  banana pie | 2018-06-19T00:00:00Z |
|  k tom | Apple juice | 2018-06-18T00:00:00Z |
| Stanly |   Apple pie | 2018-06-18T00:00:00Z |
|  kevin |  banana pie | 2018-06-18T00:00:00Z |
```

I don't know how to do second and third condition.

My expected results:

```
|   col1 |        col2 |           createDate |
+--------+-------------+----------------------+
|  U Tom |   Apple pie | 2018-06-19T00:00:00Z |
|    Tom |  banana pie | 2018-06-19T00:00:00Z |
|  S Amy |   Apple pie | 2018-06-19T00:00:00Z |
|  U tOm |   Apple pie | 2018-06-19T00:00:00Z |
|  k tom | Apple juice | 2018-06-18T00:00:00Z |
| Stanly |   Apple pie | 2018-06-18T00:00:00Z |
|  kevin |  banana pie | 2018-06-18T00:00:00Z |
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to use `CASE WHEN` on `ORDER BY`

look like this.

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
ORDER BY
 createDate DESC,
 CASE 
    WHEN col1 collate Chinese_PRC_CS_AS like '%Tom%' THEN 2
    WHEN col2 like '%apple%' THEN 1
    ELSE 0
 END DESC
```

Note :

- `collate Chinese_PRC_CS_AS` care uppercase and lowercase

sqlfiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/66fd1/2

**Result:**

```
|   col1 |        col2 |           createDate |
|--------|-------------|----------------------|
|  U Tom |   Apple pie | 2018-06-19T00:00:00Z |
|    Tom |  banana pie | 2018-06-19T00:00:00Z |
|  S Amy |   Apple pie | 2018-06-19T00:00:00Z |
|  U tOm |   Apple pie | 2018-06-19T00:00:00Z |
|  k tom | Apple juice | 2018-06-18T00:00:00Z |
| Stanly |   Apple pie | 2018-06-18T00:00:00Z |
|  kevin |  banana pie | 2018-06-18T00:00:00Z |
```

Comment: I think you can take out the %apple% part of the CASE.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question, a simple answer should be:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
ORDER BY createDate DESC, col1 , upper(col2)
```

where `upper(col2)` allow the sort to be case-insensitive

... but it isn't true only if your data are stored with a case insensitive collation, like  sql_latin1_general_cp1_ci_as

A more generic answer is :

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
ORDER BY createDate DESC
, col1 COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN 
, col2 COLLATE  sql_latin1_general_cp1_ci_as
```

=> col1 COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN  ensures a case sensitive sort of "col1"

=> col2 COLLATE  sql_latin1_general_cp1_ci_as  ensures a case INsensitive sort of "col2"

Comment: This won't do condition 2, see D-Shih's answer.  Also, SQL Server is case-insensitive by default so the `upper` isn't needed.

Comment: Aaron, SQL Server in not case-insensitive by defaut and not in any case: it depends of the data "Case collation". For sample, varchar columns with "sql_latin1_general_cp1_ci_as"  are case-insensitive, but "Latin1_General_BIN" aren't !   You are rigth, my answer is partial, because i don't take care of @marc_s data's collation

Comment: The default collation is always case-insensitive, but I suppose OP didn't tell us their collation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms143508(v=sql.105)#default-collations-in-sql-server-setup

Comment: Not every times: it depends of server default parameters, of the database defaults, of the table CREATE,...